# Is it possible to get boss souls back?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I used a boss soul before knowing you get weapons by it, is there any chance to get the soul back, but i have'nt beat the game yet, so i cant go into NG+ (if a specific boss it's "Dragonrider")

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Minor spoiler ahead]

> You can get 2 dragonrider souls in each NG cycle without using bonfire ascetic (the second one will come somewhat later in the game).

Answer (score 7):

You can get it by burning a bonfire ascetic which resets the boss in that area, but also increases the level of enemies in that area to the difficulty of New Game +.

But be careful because burning an ascetic means that when you do get to NG+, that area will be an even higher difficulty (NG++), as progressing to NG+ raises the difficulty of all areas by 1.

So while the enemies in the area are harder, the Boss is back and you can get the Boss soul.

http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Bonfire+Ascetic

Comment: Other than completing the game (which just pushes all bonfires up 1 level) this is the only way!

Comment: Thankfully it's Dragonrider *cough* cheeze him *cough* :p